# $A^{2m+1}=A+I_n$ then $\det(A)>0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries and $m$ a positive integer such that:

$$A^{2m+1}=A+I_n$$
Prove that $$\det(A)>0$$

I tried solving this problem and, by rewriting the hypothesis conditions I got that
$$(A-I_n)(A^{2m}+A^{2m-1}+\dots+A+I_n)=A$$
But we know that
$$\det(A^{2m}+A^{2m-1}+\dots+A+I_n)\ge 0$$
So how can I continue from there?

Comment: if $A^{2n+1} = A+I$ then $A(A^{2n}-I) = (A^{2n}-I)A= I$ (only factoring), and you can use the property $\text{det}(XY) = \text{det}(X)\text{det}(Y)$ and $\text{det}(I) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* It suffices to show that $A$ has not any zero or negative eigenvalues (i.e. $A$ has only positive eigenvalues or conjugate pairs of non-real eigenvalues). In turn, it suffices to prove that $x^{2m+1}=x+1$ has not any zero or negative roots. Suppose the contrary. Then $-|x|^{2m+1}=-|x|+1$, i.e. $|x|=|x|^{2m+1}+1$. Why is this equation insolvable?